# Qt tableView display image in cell and get path on click

Tags: c++, qt

I need to display in a table view in grid format, and upon click on cell I need to get the path of the image clicked, I managed to get display the image in cell,  but no I idea how to store the image path inside `QStandardItem` along withe pix map,

```
QStandardItemModel *model;
model=new QStandardItemModel();
ui->tableView->setModel( model );


QString imgPath = "/home/haris/Pictures/face/3.png";
QPixmap pix1(imgPath);
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
item->setData(QVariant(pix1), Qt::DecorationRole);
model->setItem(0, 0, item);

item = new QStandardItem();
item->setData(QVariant(pix1), Qt::DecorationRole);
model->setItem(0, 1, item);
```

Comment: You can try it like this `item->setData(QVariant(imgPath ), Qt::UserRole);`

Comment: Thanks that works great, if you added it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save any data in `QStandardItem` using [setData()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData). For it pass `Qt::UserRole` as third param.

**Example:**

```
item->setData(QVariant(imgPath ), Qt::UserRole);
```